# SSIS Package with embedded dll

Tags: c#, dll, ssis, package

I have designed an application that someone can install on a personal workstation and be able to generate automatically an SSIS Package. This SSIS Package now should include a Script Task.

This script task has to reference a DLL file, which contains already developed code that we need to use. So in order to achieve this goal, I have seen and tried two possible solutions:

- Register the DLL into the GAG and reference the DDL in the script task project.
- Place the DLL into a static path and reference the DDL in the script task project.

But I am looking for a more elegant solution, like embed the DLL references into the SSIS Package definition. So everyone can deploy this SSIS Package.

This approach if is possible will have many advantages:

- There is no need to check the existence of the reference path\file.dll
- There is no need to check the compatibility between the version of the DLL and the code inside the script task
- There is no read file permission issues

After a lot of research, I concluded that embedding DLL inside the DTSX definition is not possible, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

SSIS Package is an XML code which is executed by SSIS engine. It is not a universal container for data, resources, etc. SSIS Project is not such a container either, it simply a ZIP archive of XML files with predefined extensions and content. So, in SSIS infrastructure you have no place to put your DLL.
From the other end of the story, SSIS Script task is executed by SSIS Engine, which needs to locate (a.k.a resolve) and load your specific DLL. It can do it from these places:

- File path which is specified in DLL reference
- Folder where SSIS Engine binary is located
- GAC

Again, no SSIS infrastructure in this list.
In your specific scenario, I would recommend to include DLL into the mentioned installer and install it to the GAC. It is quite easy to implement and native for Windows OS.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's true that DTSX it is not a universal container, but has a lot of features, for example, it can host a script Task with C# Code inside. Then the problem starts if you need to reference a compiled code like a DLL. So i am looking for all possible alternatives.